# onclick checkbox , hide a div and show another div

Tags: jquery

I havent actually done any code for this, was searching on internet and found this article:

http://iamzed.com/jquery/showhidediv.html

Was thinking, for our purposes...

Part of a form we are making, normal display. is like this:

[image]

And checking the checkbox, hides the above div and shows this div..

[image]

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question 422. What specifically do you want to do?

Comment: Apologies. On checking checkbox, I want to hide DIV ONE and show DIV TWO, and on unchecking, hide DIV TWO and show DIV ONE

Comment: @422 there are 100s of questions like this.. u should search first..

Comment: I havent seen any, I see lots about onclick SHOW. But nothing on onClick HIDE one thing and Show another... perhaps I should be using toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to emulate what I saw in the pictures [in fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fcBQp/) It's not styled but it has the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: One issue I have is, we style our button like this: <button id="PlaceOrderButton" class="medium pink button" value="Place Standard Order" name="submit" type="submit" style="float:right;"></button> How would I dynamically add the TEXT on the button ... ?

Comment: As you are using the `<button>` tag instead of `<input type="button">`, you need to use `.html` instead of `.val`. Also you would put the text between the button tags like this: `<button>Button Text</button>`. Here it is in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcBQp/1/)

Comment: Sweet, yeah I had done the Text inside button, but forgot to change val to html. Cheers William

Comment: Lastly, if standard div show, I want to display <div class="showPrice">$149.99</div>
and if featured wanted to display <div class="showPrice">$299.99</div>

Comment: Would this be correct: $( "#showthePrice" ).html( "<div class='featuredPrice'>$299.99</div>"); and $( "#showthePrice" ).html( "<div class='standardPrice'>$149.99</div>");

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Two important things to note: `.val` accesses the `value` property of the element, and `.html` accesses the `innerHTML` property. So, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have proper html structure, that everything you want to hide is in div with id yourOldContent and what you want to show is in div with id yourDivWithNewContent (which is initially hidden with display: none;), and the checkbox has id checkboxId, you can use following code:

```
 $('#checkboxId').click(function(){
  $('#yourDivWithNewContent').toggle();
  $('yourOldContent').toggle();
});
```

Comment: hmmm.. that sounds like what we want, so checking the checkbox, hides original button and shows div 2, and unchecking reverts to old content .. is that correct ? The issue seemingly is to hide old and show new. I see lots of code, for on click show, but not hide one thing onclick and show another

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      $("#box1").show();
      $("#button_feature").show();
      $("#button_normal").hide();
   }
   else{
      $("#box1").hide();
      $("#button_feature").hide();
      $("#button_normal").show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Surely that just hides DIV ONE ?

Comment: @422: yes, it hides one div (that big box) and switch buttons